# I can't press the utf8 encoding value (if-else) in php

Tags: php, html

My php code consists of the following if-else conditional statements

I don't understand why I can not enter values with utf8 characters `ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.`, eg: `Bąk`, `Królikowska` etc ...

```
    $r_nazwisko = $_POST['r_nazwisko'];

        if (strlen($r_nazwisko) < 1) {
...
        }

        if (strlen($r_nazwisko) > 16) {
...
}

        if (ctype_alnum($r_nazwisko) == false) {

...
        }

        if (preg_match("/[^A-z_-]/", $r_nazwisko) == 1) {
...
        }
```

Comment: Always use mb_ functions with utf8.  mb_strlen

Comment: okkay, but it is still no working.

Comment: Define not working.  Provide a simple reproducible example.